# How to make Shiny Datatable Column Filter search more friendly

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, dt

I was wondering how we can make the column filter search in shiny datatables more friendly. With its default version, you can only search one character at a time, and then it jumps out and you have to reclick the filter box to type another character, which is very frustrating and time-consuming. I was wondering if there was a way to make it more friendly.

Currently I have the solution for the general search box:

```
tags$script(JS("$(function(){
                        var myTable=$('#myTable').dataTable();
                        $('.dataTables_filter input')
                        .unbind('keypress keyup')
                        .bind('keypress keyup', function(e){
                        if ($(this).val().length < 3 && e.keyCode != 13) return;
                        myTable.fnFilter($(this).val());
                        });
                        });")),
```

Does anyone know how to make the column filter equally friendly?

My server.R is:

```
library(shiny)

library(DT)

source("update.R")

shinyServer(function(input,output,session){

dataInput<-reactive(main())

output$table<-DT::renderDataTable(
  withProgress(message="Compiling",
               datatable(dataInput()[which(dataInput()$Date<=input$dates[2]&dataInput()$Date>=input$dates[1]),],
                         extensions=c("Buttons","FixedHeader","AutoFill","ColReorder"),
                         filter="top",
                         rownames=FALSE,
                         options=list(searchHighlight=TRUE,
                                      search=list(caseInsensitive=TRUE),
                                      dom='Blfrtip',
                                      buttons=c("copy","csv","print","colvis"),
                                      autoWidth=TRUE,
                                      lengthMenu=c(25,50,100,1000),
                                      pageLength=25,
                                      fixedHeader=TRUE,
                                      autoFill=TRUE,
                                      colReorder=TRUE,
                                      style="width:100%"
                         ),
                         escape=FALSE) %>% formatCurrency(c(22:25,28:33),currency="",digits=0)
  )
)

output$download<-downloadHandler(
  filename=function(){
    paste("form_d_",Sys.Date(),".csv",sep="")
  },
  content=function(con){
    write.csv(dataInput(),con,row.names=FALSE)
  }
)

observeEvent(input$btn,
             session$sendCustomMessage("pager",input$pagination-1)
)
})
```

and my ui.R is:

```
library(shiny)

library(DT)

shinyUI(
  fluidPage(

  titlePanel("", windowTitle="Form D Database"),

  tags$head(tags$style("#table  {white-space: nowrap;  }")),

  fluidRow(column(5,downloadButton("download",label=h5("Download all"))),
           column(3,dateRangeInput("dates",label=h4("Date:"),start="2008-05-30",min="2008-05-30")
           )
  ),

  mainPanel(helpText("These four buttons only work with the view. To download everything, click the 'Download all' button."),

        dataTableOutput("table"),

        tags$script(JS("$(function(){
                        var myTable=$('#myTable').dataTable();
                        $('.dataTables_filter input')
                        .unbind('keypress keyup')
                        .bind('keypress keyup', function(e){
                        if ($(this).val().length < 3 && e.keyCode != 13) return;
                        myTable.fnFilter($(this).val());
                        });
                        });")),

        numericInput("pagination",label=h4("Page:"),value=1),

        actionButton("btn","Go to Page"),

        tags$script(HTML(
          "Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('pager',function(page) {
          $('#'+'table').find('table').DataTable().page(page).draw(false);
          })"))
  )
  )
)
```

where `main()` is a function from `update.R` that returns a `data.frame`.

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example of the column filters forcing you to search one character at a time?

Comment: When I run your code without the javascript I don't have any issues. You are saying that if you start entering info in the column filter that it focuses away from the input field after each letter is inputted? That doesn't happen to me. What version of DT are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 0.1.57. What you're saying is exactly the problem I am having with my app. Do you mean that even without the JS code block in `ui.R` you  can still type in multiple characters in the general search box without jumping out of the search box every time you enter a character?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: I took out the JS block, and yes there is no such problem in the general search box but it still exists in the column filters.

Comment: No problems for me. I guess you could try updating DT its at version 0.1.66 now I beleive

Comment: I checked the updates in my RStudio and it says that my DT is the newest version. Did you get it through `devtools`?

Comment: Yes, you definitely want the development version on github. A lot has changed, and you should expect a new DT to hit CRAN reasonably soon.

Comment: I reinstalled DT from Github, and it works! No more one-character-at-a-time issues any more. Thanks a lot! I am also wondering did the new DT package include the pagination plug-in (or extension? I forgot the exact thing it was) where you can enter a number for a page? I included it in my app, but it'd still be better if you can put it inside the DT.